# resourcePath not working Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5

I have created a sqlite database containing data for my app, and dragged it into the supporting files group in Xcode.

When I try to access it using:

`NSString *bundlePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"database.db"];`

It does not read the file. However if I put in the full file path:

`NSString *bundlePath = @"Users/xxxx/Apps/App/database.db";`

The app works fine.

---

I printed out the file path from:

`NSString *bundlePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"database.db"];`

and it is:

`/Users/xxx/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/EE614EFA-BAF9-478E-xxxx-xxxx/App.app/database.db`

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to deal with paths is to let the API take care of the details about "appending" stuff to path strings.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"database" 
                                                 ofType:@"db"];
```

Comment: When I try that, path evaluates to nil.

Comment: Select the file on in the Xcode Project Navigator (to the left) and make sure that your target is checked under "Target Membership" in the File Inspector (to the right). -- Also double-check the spelling of the file names.

Answer (score 1):

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"database" 
                                                 ofType:@".SQLite"];