# Getting a nil path from NSBundle

Tags: objective-c, nsbundle, xcode4.4

I have created a new folder in my project in which I have copied an image (called "io.jpg").
I also have checked on build phases -> copy bundle resources and the file is there.
So I am trying to get the path of this image:

```
NSBundle* bundle=[NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString* path=[bundle pathForResource: @"io" ofType: @"jpg"];
NSLog(@"%@",path);
```

But it prints (null), I also have tried this way:

```
NSBundle* bundle=[NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString* path=[bundle pathForImageResource: @"io"];
NSLog(@"%@",path);
```

But it still prints (null).
What's the problem?

Comment: Have you looked in the actual built product to make sure the file got copied correctly?

Comment: Yes, the file is in the app directory.

Comment: possible duplicate of [resourcePath not working Xcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11447010/resourcepath-not-working-xcode)

Comment: In that question there isn't the answer (the check box target membershit was already checked), so I don't think it's a duplicate.

Comment: 1) Does [NSBundle mainBundle] return non-nil?   2) have you tried URLforResource instead? (wild guess)

Comment: have you created a folder reference or a group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess, given that you said you created a new **folder** in your Xcode project is that you have created a blue folder reference and your image resource is in a sub directory of your bundle.

I'd be willing to bet it's not a bug with NSBundle, given how old and crutial the class is to the Foundation framework.

Try and access your resource using the more specific instance method

```
- (NSString *)pathForResource:(NSString *)name ofType:(NSString *)extension inDirectory:(NSString *)subpath
```

where `subpath` is the name of the **folder reference** I am guessing you created.

Answer (score 6):

Go to : Target -> "Build Phases" -> "copy bundle Resources" Then add that particular file here.

clean the project and RUN. It works. :)

Answer (score 3):

You'll get a nil path if the resource you're requesting doesn't exist in the output (or doesn't exist where it should). That's really the only reason I've seen.

Forget about proving it should exist, and just check the output to make sure it does.

(Remember also that filenames are case sensitive.)

To clarify, you should be looking in the **output bundle** in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerviedData/Project-{GUID}/Build/Products`. Your image will be missing.

Comment: The image is there, I have also tried printing bundle's path, and went into it's directory and I noticed that under Contents->Resources there is the image "io.jpg".

Comment: It should be in the top level of YourApplication.app, not in a Resources subdirectory.

Comment: @StevenFisher I'm using Xcode 6 - where can I see the resource files? They're not in Products or Debug-iphonesimulator.

Comment: Individual graphics are inside the app bundle: Control click as above. If you're using asset catalogs you won't see them; the equivalent is the Assets.car file. You're probably better off asking a new question with screenshots of your images (within the asset bundle/project) and the code you're using to try to access them. Things are a lot different now.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like this a few weeks ago. And it turned out I just hadn't ticked a box. Here is the answer I got when I asked.

"Select the file on in the Xcode Project Navigator (to the left) and make sure that your target is checked under "Target Membership" in the File Inspector (to the right). -- Also double-check the spelling of the file names – Mundi"

Comment: So this question is a duplicate of that question?

Comment: Yes. If you forget to check the box, the file won't actually be in the application's bundle.

Answer (score 0):

All of this is *kind of overkill* if you're just trying to get an image.  Let's say you have included `bundleImage.PNG` in your application bundle.. somewhere, somehow…

`NSImage *image = [NSImage imageNamed:@"bundleImage"];`

will, for sure.. find it… If it's there… Can't get more simple, right?

If - *in the off chance* - it's a slightly more complicated situation, like the image is in a loadable bundle or framework - you can use code similar to the following (a class category on NSImage) which will also return the resource.

```
+ (id) imageInFrameworkWithFileName:(NSString *) fileName {
   NSBundle *b = [NSBundle bundleForClass: [DummyClass class]];
   return [self imageWithFileName: fileName inBundle: b];
}
```

To be honest, I don't really understand the concept of, or how such a "Dummy class" works.. but this is what it looks like

```
@interface DummyClass : NSObject
@end
@implementation DummyClass 
@end
```

Comment: Assuming 'DummyClass' is also in the bundle/framework as the image resource you're looking for.

Comment: @Jessedc No, I just include the `@interface DummyClass` before my `@interface NSImage (MyCategory)` and then I can use it anywhere that has inherited that `#import`'ed category..

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the image from your app.And then adding it again.And clean your build before running it.See if it helps.Otherwise please give a screenshot of your project navigator showing where is the image added.It must be in the top level of your Application.app.Is it somwhere inside any folder/sub-folder.