# Console application - NSBundle can't get file path

Tags: objective-c, macos, foundation

New to Mac console applications. Never done it before, but I want to code with Objective-C, so I chose "Foundation" while creating the application with Xcode.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        NSString *contentPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Input" ofType:@"txt"];
        NSLog(@"%@",contentPath);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

The path is null.

I followed an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7835776/555690 from a related question, but it did not fix it.

Then I took a look at [Getting a nil path from NSBundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11706093/getting-a-nil-path-from-nsbundle), but the problem they have was a directory (I don't have directories - I just placed my file in the project's root).

Why else could I be getting null for this file's path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's coming up null because typically when you have an .app with bundled resources you would need to add a file named Input.txt into your Supporting Files folder, or Resources folder. Since you're writing a console application I don't understand why you would being do that.

Before adding Input.txt to Supporting Files:

```
2013-05-09 19:23:40.228 tester[2847:303] (null)
```

After adding Input.txt to Supporting Files:

```
2013-05-09 19:21:00.306 tester[2807:303] /Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/tester-gjrofdlcblvmplbjdvvfhieiymzh/Build/Products/Debug/tester.app/Contents/Resources/Input.txt
```

Comment: He's not writing a .app though, so there's no Resources directory

Comment: @Catfish_Man — I don't know why he wants to do it that way, I'm just explaining the reason behind the null message.

Comment: @l'L'l: Sorry, this is what I did to read files in my iOS apps, so I just copied the code. Is there a better way?

Comment: @Omega - Are you writing a console app, or are you planning on making it an actual application with a gui, etc. — and what's the Input.txt for exactly.

Comment: @l'L'l: A console application. I simply want to open the text file, and read line by line. The purpose (which I don't think it matters) is create a .plist file using the info found in the text file.

Comment: If you're reading a text file that is not part of your application then you would typically do something like `NSString *info = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"/path/to/myfile.txt"];` or use `NSHomeDirectory ()` to get the path of the file you want to read. The code you are showing is specifically meant for a file that is included with your application.

Comment: @Omega - this might shed some light on things > http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/12/command-line-tools-tutorial-1/

Answer (score 3):

Your application doesn't have a bundle (which is a specially structured directory), so bundle resource lookups will not look anything up for it.

Comment: As a solution to this problem, instead of using `NSBundle`, use the actual path of the resource. `[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"/Users/Bob/Desktop/console-app/console-app/file.txt"];` should work assuming the file exists.